# Bind data to CartesianChart without setting datacontext using Live Chart in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, livecharts

When I set up datacontext like this then everything works fine.
My backend code

```
public partial class ucMyGraph : UserControl
{
    public ucMyGraph()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public ChartValues<decimal> ChartValues
    {
        get { return (ChartValues<decimal>)GetValue(ChartValuesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChartValuesProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartValuesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ChartValues", typeof(ChartValues<decimal>), typeof(ucWatchlistGraph),
            new PropertyMetadata(new ChartValues<decimal> { 1816.59m, 1818.85m, 1820.71m, 1821.03m, 1824.32m, 1825.62m, 1825.58m, 1826.71m, 1825.62m, 1824.76m, 1825.05m,
        1823.71m, 1824.66m, 1825.54m, 1824.67m, 1826.1m, 1820.66m, 1822.35m, 1822.06m, 1822.22m }));
}
```

And here is the xmal

```
 <lvc:CartesianChart Height="60" Width="120"  Margin="0" Padding="0" x:Name="cartesianChart" 
                            AnimationsSpeed="0:0:0.5" Hoverable="False" 
                            DataTooltip="{x:Null}">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:LineSeries Values="{Binding ChartValues}" 
                            PointGeometry="{x:Null}" 
                            LineSmoothness="0.1"
                            StrokeThickness="1"                                 
                            Stroke="#43A047">
            </lvc:LineSeries>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

When I erase this line
`DataContext = this` 
form the constractor and try to bind ChartValues using relative resource like this (`Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ucMyGraph}}, Path=ChartValues`) it doesn't work. I'm wondering why it is important to set datacontext for showing the live chart graph. I'm new in this topic so I need your help. I want to show the graph without initialize datacontext. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

DataContext is use for store data to display to UI(User Interface). If you set Values="{Binding ChartValues}", it will understand that you are binding ChartValues of DataContext. In the constructor ucMyGraph() you assigned DataContext = this (ucMyGraph), which mean the "Values" will display the value of property ChartValues of this(ucMyGraph). If the DataContext you assigned doesn't have the property ChartValues, the binding will not work.

Comment: Try to use code formatting for any code examples for better clarity